# Alternative use for uarial package in Overleaf for LaTeX

Tags: latex

For a project I am using Overleaf for LaTex and I require the uarial package that I initialised liked this:

```
\RequirePackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

With this I get the LaTeX error: File 'uarial.sty' not found and the file cannot be compiled. If I were using Linux I would need to install and I saw [here](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019) that the non-free fonts packages don't work on overleaf anymore. If I try to use the free package helvet or tgheros instead like this:

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I get the error Fatal Package fontspec Error (for the file /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty which I don't have direct access to anyways, right?) and an Emergency stop. How do I change this or what can I use as an alternative to uarial instead?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar `LaTeX error: File 'uarial.sty' not found` error and I solved it by uploading [uarial.sty](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial/latex/uarial.sty) to my project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to **change the compiler** for the tgheros font. This solves the compiling error and is further explained [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler).